# Как происходит создание объекта функции?

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в закулисьях этого кода:

```
def someFunction():
    list = []
    for i in range(5):
        list.append(lambda x: i ** x)
    return list

#вызов функции
list = someFunction()
print(list[1](2))
```

По идее, результатом этого кода должна выступать единица, но на самом деле выводится 16. Я не совсем понимаю, как работает эта программа. По-моему:

Компилятор начинает свою работу с 1-ой строки. Видит ***def*** и пропускает всю функцию. Затем добирается до строки

```
list = someFunction()
```

после которой начинает интерпретировать функцию **someFunction**. Добирается до цикла **for**, и начинается первая итерация. Но команда, добавляющая элемент в конец списка, в качестве аргумента принимает функцию, которая, в свою очередь, еще не получила в распоряжение свой аргумент. Что добавилось в список? Я предполагаю, что создался объект функции, который связался с конкретным элементом списка. Так, я думаю, происходит на всех итерациях. После чего функция возвращает список, в котором находятся ссылки на созданные объекты функций. Если всё так и есть на самом деле, то это логично.

Но что происходит при чтении элемента из списка? Окей. Если выплывает 16 вместо 1, скорее всего, все объекты функций в качестве итерационной переменной принимают 4-ку, т.е. последнюю итерацию. И здесь не совсем понятно, почему при создании объекта функции не сохранилось значение счетчика цикла? Предполагаю, что вы можете мне сказать: "А как, по-твоему, это значение сохранится, если его нет в параметрах **lambda**-функции?". Но тогда как она находит и подставляет последнюю итерацию? Да и вообще, пока писал этот пост еще больше запутался: с чего бы это компилятор создает объект-функции до того, как эта функция вызывается? Ведь объект функции someFunction конструировался тогда, когда мы вызвали эту функцию. А объекты lambda-функции создались ещё до их вызова.

Будьте добры, помогите разобраться в данном вопросе. Спасибо.

Comment: *И здесь не совсем понятно, почему при создании объекта функции не сохранилось значение счетчика цикла* - она же ссылается на переменную i, которая после всех итераций осталась равна 4. Насколько понимаю, это механизм, идентичный замыканиям в javascript, и который можно разрешить еще одной вложенной лямбдой, внутри которой i будет оставаться постоянным.

Comment: похожая проблема: [Why results of map() and list comprehension are different?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/139819/4279)

Comment: Питон FAQ: [Why do lambdas defined in a loop with different values all return the same result?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)

Answer (score 4):

Переменная в вашем примере всегда будет равна 4 потому, что поиск переменной в объемлющей области видимости (по правилу LEGB) происходит в момент вызова вложенной функции, а не при создании объекта. Т.е. внутри лямбда-функции i - это "ссылка на i в объемлющей области", а не "ссылка на `int(0)`" или "ссылка на `int(4)`".
Пример из ответа @aleks.andr с аргументом по умолчанию сработает потому, что вычисление значения по умолчанию происходит один раз в момент создания вложенной функции (что, кстати, тоже способно приводить к интересным эффектам, если создавать mutable-объект и изменять его внутри функции: `def f(a=[]): a.append(0) ; print(a)`)

P.S. Не перекрывайте builtin `list` в своем коде, это может привести к удивительным последствиям.

Answer (score 3):

> *И здесь не совсем понятно, почему при создании объекта функции не сохранилось значение счетчика цикла* - она же ссылается на переменную i, которая после всех итераций осталась равна 4.

Вам действительно нужно захватить переменную `i` при объявлении лямбды. Вот рабочий код, возвращающий вашу единицу:

```
def someFunction():
    list = []
    for i in range(5):
        list.append(lambda x,i=i: i ** x)
    return list

#вызов функции
list = someFunction()
print(list[1](2))
```