# Python динамическое создание методов класса

Tags: python, классы

Нужно написать родительский класс DictAttr так, чтобы у наследника динамически определялся ключ по наличию метода get_KEY

```
class DictAttr:
def __init__(self, args):
    if isinstance(args, list):
        args = dict(args)

    for k in args:
        setattr(self, k, args[k])
        setattr(self, 'get_' + k, lambda: getattr(self, k))

def __getitem__(self, item):
    return getattr(self, item)

def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    setattr(self, key, value)
```

x = DictAttr({'k': 5, 'l': 'ss', 'g': 4})

print(x.get_k())

В итоге у меня все созданые методы возвращают значение последней пары. При этом следующие конструкции работают правильно:

```
x['k']
x.k
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как происходит создание объекта функции? (Python)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468723/23044)

Comment: Вместо DictAttr, можно `types.SimpleNamespace` класс попробовать. [Можно ли как-нибудь упростить инициализацию классов на Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495719/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эту строчку:

```
setattr(self, 'get_' + k, lambda: getattr(self, k))
```

замените на

```
setattr(self, 'get_' + k, lambda k=k: getattr(self, k))
```

Иначе у вас лямбда хранит ссылку на переменную цикла k. Соответственно, когда цикл подставляет в эту переменную новые значения, ссылка внутри каждой лямбды будет смотреть уже на это новое значение, и оно будет одним и тем же для всех лямбд.

Подробнее гуглите по запросу "python замыкания"

PS: Назвать класс ДиктАтр - забавный каламбур :)

PS2: Но вообще, это всё здорово для учебной задачи, но в боевом коде никогда не пишите подобного. Большинство задач, которые пытаются решить динамическим созданием аттрибутов и тп. успешно решаются банальным словарём - и с гораздо меньшим количеством гемороя.

Comment: Спасибо, просто делаю задачи отсюда http://pyobject.ru/blog/2010/02/04/python-quiz/

Answer (score 0):

Можно было гораздо проще сделать:

```
class DictAttr(dict):

  def __getattr__(self, attr):

    if attr.startswith('get_'):
      attr = attr[4:]

    return self[attr]
```